# How to use Helm to grep across a list of xz compressed files?

Tags: occur, helm-grep, helm-ag

I'm trying to implement a simple helm extension for work which among other things provides an action to "grep across selected log file candidates". I've got this all working for actions like this:

```lisp
    (defun visit-logs-action (log-directory log-name)
      "Visit the selected log files"
      (let ((full-paths (mapcar (lambda (fn) (concat log-directory "/" fname)) 
                                (helm-marked-candidates))))
      (mapc #'find-file full-paths)))
```

(in the above I pass `log-directory` myself from a lambda and helm gives me `log-name` but I ignore it to instead consider all selected candidates (based on reading [handling multiple selections](https://wikemacs.org/wiki/How_to_write_helm_extensions#Handling_multiple_selections))

I'm having trouble with a "grep across selected log files" primarily because they are `xz` compressed. I tried looking at the `occur` family of functions or even `helm-swoop` but those go off buffers. The closest I've come so far is with `helm-ag` by doing something like this:

```lisp
    (defun grep-logs-action (log-directory log-name)
      "Any swoop/helm-ag/occur over the files would be great here."
      (let ((helm-ag-command-option "-z"))
        (helm-do-ag log-directory (helm-marked-candidates))))
```

but the output of that looks corrupt. Haven't found a good hook either for this in `helm-grep`

I also tried to find a way to use `helm-rg` but so far that does not seem to accept a list of paths and instead only a directory (and that works poorly because the log directory is huge with too many large logs). Am wondering if there are other simple alternatives that I could try here to hop into a swoop/grep/occur really anything to fulfill that extra functionality

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Things First

`helm-find-files` (Helm FF) already includes an action to run `zgrep` on the marked candidates, you can run it with `M-g z` (`C-u` to recurse).

But maybe your `zgrep` doesn’t support the .xz format, so...

#### Let’s Use ripgrep (`rg`) Instead

Unfortunately, the_silver_searcher (`ag`) has [a bug](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/1164), so we’ll have to stick to `rg`.

```lisp
(defun helm-ff-rg-z (_candidate)
  "Grep with `rg -z' from Helm FF."
  (let* ((candidates (helm-marked-candidates :with-wildcard t))
         (relative-candidates (mapcar (lambda (candidate)
                                        (file-relative-name candidate helm-ff-default-directory))
                                      candidates))
         (helm-grep-ag-command (concat "rg -z --color=always --smart-case --no-heading --line-number --with-filename %s -- %s"
                                       " "
                                       (mapconcat (lambda (relative-candidate)
                                                    ;; make sure everything is quoted properly
                                                    (string-replace "%" "%%" (shell-quote-argument relative-candidate)))
                                                  relative-candidates
                                                  " "))))
    (helm-grep-ag helm-ff-default-directory helm-current-prefix-arg)))

(defun helm-ff-run-rg-z ()
  "Run `helm-ff-rg-z' from Helm FF with a key binding."
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action 'helm-ff-rg-z)))
(put 'helm-ff-run-rg-z 'helm-only t)

(push '("Grep with `rg -z' (`C-u' to select file types)" . helm-ff-rg-z) (cdr (last helm-find-files-actions)))
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "M-g R") 'helm-ff-run-rg-z)
```

You can now mark some candidates (including whole directories) and grep them with `rg -z` by pressing `M-g R` from Helm FF.

#### Result

##### Marked candidates

[image: Screenshot showing marked candidates]

##### Grep For `foo`

Both files contain `foo`:

[image: Screenshot showing grepping for foo]

##### Grep For `baz`

Only the second file contains `baz`:

[image: Screenshot showing grepping for baz]

Comment: wow this is awesome! I have not seen `with-helm-alive-p` and `helm-exit-and-execute-action` nor `helm-only` before - makes me wonder if it is buggy that I am not using them in how i've been writing helm extensions...

Comment: oh btw I had to change the `--` to a third `%s` for some reason to get the code snippet above to work (not sure exactly why yet)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `zrgrep` would be the normal way.

I've just noticed there's no `zlgrep` though -- that would be a good feature request to <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug` for.  A manual workaround might be <kbd>M-!</kbd> `zgrep -nH <pattern> <files>` <kbd>RET</kbd> and then <kbd>M-x</kbd> `grep-mode` in the output buffer (although the command line options might vary between systems).

Comment: For now I've ended up nastily copying the relevant log globs to a temporary directory and deploying `helm-rg` onto them as the `--search-zip` option I can configure for it understands `xz`